# SQL Query to CAST and SUM columns in two different Tables having Multiple Entries

Tags: mysql, vb.net, search, join

Need help in Building a Query which can select a Item and sum up its QTY which is in 2 different Tables.

Example Scenario:

Table 1:

ID | ITEM_NAME | QTY |

1  | Item_Desc1  | 0   |

2  | Item_Desc2   | 2   |

3  | Item_Desc3   | 4   |

4  | Item_Desc4   | 0   |

Table 2:

ID | ITEM_ID | BATCHNO | QTY

1  | 1       | B1      | 100

2  | 1       | B2      | 100

3  | 2       | B3      | 0

4  | 3       | B2      | 100

5  | 4       | B2      | 200

6  | 4       | B3      | 100

Need a Query to show in a Data grid Table as follows:

ID | Item_Name | QTY

1 | Item_Desc1 | 200

2 | Item_Desc2 | 2

3 | Item_Desc3 | 104

4 | Item_Desc4 | 300

Note:

This Query should be useful to run a Search query using 'LIKE' operator by using which User can search for Items Needed

[SAMPLE Image of My APPLICATION to Run Search query using Table 1 and Table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOiGd.png)
[SAMPLE Image of My APPLICATION DATABASE - TABLE2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwPYe.png)
[SAMPLE Image of My APPLICATION DATABASE - TABLE1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZiHp.png)

Answer (score 0):

To get sum from 2 table you can use following query

```
select a.ID, a.ITEM_NAME, a.QTY + coalesce(b.QTY,0)
from Table1 a
left join (
  select ITEM_ID,sum(QTY) QTY
  from Table2
  group by ITEM_ID
) b on a.ID = b.ITEM_ID
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4ce078/3)

Comment: Correct My code If possible.`SELECT a.id as [Item#],a.ITEMNAME as [ITEM NAME / Full Description],(cast(a.QTY as numeric(19,2)) + coalesce(cast(b.QTY as numeric(19,2)))) as [Quantity] FROM [iBillDB].[dbo].[Inventory] a left join ( select ITEMID,sum(cast(QTY as numeric(19,2))) QTY from [iBillDB].[dbo].[BATCHENTRY]  group by ITEMID) b on a.ID = b.ITEMID`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query

```
select tbl1.id as ID,tbl1.Item_Name, tbl.qty+sum(tbl2.qty) as QTY 
from table1  as tbl1 
JOIN table2 as tbl2 
ON tbl1.id = tbl2.id group by tbl2.item_id
```